# How can I handle the deletion of these items from SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm building an app that will silence people's ringers based on their location.  I use a PlacePicker API, then save the name of the place to SharedPreferences and add it to a ListView.  I have problems with deleting the items, though.  When the user long clicks a listview item, it is supposed to be deleted from SharedPreferences.  The problem is, after the first deletion, my method of referring to which SharedPrefs item to delete is bad and it doesn't work.  How can I fix it?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder;
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST;
ListView placeListView;
ArrayList<String> placeArrayList;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
ArrayList<Double> latitudeList;
Integer counter;
LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;
double lat;
double lng;
Place place;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    placeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.placeListView);
    latitudeList = new ArrayList<>();
    placeArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, placeArrayList);
    placeListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);


    placeListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {






            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                    .setMessage("Do you want to delete this place?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                            placeArrayList.remove(position);


                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("name" + position).apply();


                            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();



            return false;
        }
    });




    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null){


        lat = location.getLatitude();

        lng = location.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(lat) + String.valueOf(lng), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }else{

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to get location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("counter", 0);

    counter = sharedPreferences.getInt("counter", -1);




    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
            builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            pickPlace();


        }
    });
   }

public void pickPlace(){

    try {
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }






}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
           // String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            //Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            counter = sharedPreferences.getInt("counter", -1);


                counter = counter + 1;
                sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("counter", counter).apply();


           LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();

            sharedPreferences.edit().putFloat("latitude" + String.valueOf(counter), (float) latLng.latitude).apply();

            sharedPreferences.edit().putFloat("longitude" + String.valueOf(counter), (float) latLng.longitude).apply();




                   placeArrayList.add(place.getName().toString());

            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("name" + placeArrayList.size(), place.getName().toString()).apply();








arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();








        }

    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    for (int i = counter; i >= 0; i--){


        if (lat >= sharedPreferences.getFloat("latitude" + String.valueOf(i), -1) - .005 &&
                lat <= sharedPreferences.getFloat("latitude" + String.valueOf(i), -1) + .005 &&
                lng >= sharedPreferences.getFloat("longitude" + String.valueOf(i), -1) - .005 &&
                lng <= sharedPreferences.getFloat("longitude" + String.valueOf(i), -1) + .005){


            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);


        }

    }



}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a listener for preferences changes. Something like this:

```
preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

            }
        });
```

You receive the key has changed and now you can check te value of this or if this key exists.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: How do I use that to refer to the SharedPreferences item I need?  my problem is that once an item is deleted, the items further down in the listview shift, and I can no longer use "position" to refer to them in SharedPreferences.    for instance, if the third item gets deleted, the 4th takes its place.  then when the user tries to delete that one, they can't because it has a tag of 4, when the position is 3